# passing parameter to url via <a> tag int html

Tags: javascript, html

I have in a variable (`var lan= urlParam('language')`) the selected language.
I want to pass this language as parameter (without using PHP) in a url in an "`a`" tag, like this:

```
<a href="http://hotelscombined.sitewish.gr/HotelNameSearch.aspx?languageCode=lan">
```

but it doesn't work.

I am waiting for your answers.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: You want to dynamically, using JavaScript, add a new GET parameter to every link that is on the page. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your url is inside a string, so it won't put the value of your variable, but just the string "lan".

Give an ID to your link, so you can take it and change its url with javascript.

```
<a id="foo" href="http://hotelscombined.sitewish.gr/HotelNameSearch.aspx">
```

Then, with JS

```
document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('href', 'http://hotelscombined.sitewish.gr/HotelNameSearch.aspx?languageCode=' + lan);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just use document.write to print the link and add the variable as the language parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<a href=\"http://hotelscombined.sitewish.gr/HotelNameSearch.aspx?languageCode=" + lan + "\">link description</a>");</script>
```